# How to remove this fatal error from WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a custom plugin. "Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration" is my plugin's class which I have used to integrate with Woocommerce but this is showing an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration::admin_options() in E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\settings\class-wc-settings-integrations.php:80 Stack trace: #0 E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): WC_Settings_Integrations->output('') #1 E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\views\html-admin-settings.php(26): do_action('woocommerce_set...') #4 E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\class-wc-admin-settings.php(169): include('E:\xamp\htdocs\...') #5 E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\class-wc-admin-menus.php(204): WC_Admin_Settings::output() #6 E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): WC_Admin_Menus->settings_page('') #7 E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): in E:\xamp\htdocs\wwp\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\settings\class-wc-settings-integrations.php on line 80

This is code for my custom class integration:

```
class Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration {
/**
* Construct the plugin.
*/
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'init' ) );
}
/**
* Initialize the plugin.
*/
public function init() {
    // Checks if WooCommerce is installed.
    if ( class_exists( 'WC_Integration' ) ) {
        // Include our integration class.
        include_once 'viral_throb_wc_integration.php';
        // Register the integration.
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_integrations', array( $this, 'add_integration' ) );
    } else {
        // throw an admin error if you like
    }
}
/**
 * Add a new integration to WooCommerce.
 */
public function add_integration( $integrations ) {
    $integrations[] = 'Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration';
    return $integrations;
}
}

$viral_throb_integration = new Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration( __FILE__ );
```

Comment: I suspect readers will need to see your code, and some more information about your task. What is `Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration` and have you confirmed that the method `admin_options()` exists?

Comment: i am developing a custom plugin. "Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration" is my plugin's class which i have used to integrate with woocommerce but this is showing an error "Call to undefined method Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration::admin_options()". i am sharing my code with you.

Comment: Surely if `Vrial_Throb_WC_Integration` is your own class, you know what methods it has in it, right?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my integration code in the question.

Comment: OK, there's no `admin_options()` in there.

Comment: admin_options() does exists in abstract-wc-integration.php

Comment: _"admin_options() does exists in abstract-wc-integration.php"_, well do you think you should show that code, then? Please don't ask me for help directly - I _am_ helping, by assisting you to ask an understandable question. Let's see if we can get it to contain a useful amount of information before it is put on hold.

Comment: some classes needed to be define in my plugin too i have solved my issue thank you for your concern @LoicTheAztec